# In Python 2.7, how do I override the string representation of a single function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I override the string representation for a single function in Python?

What I have tried:

```
>>> def f(): pass
... 
>>> f
<function f at 0x7f7459227758>
>>> f.__str__ = lambda self: 'qwerty'
>>> f
<function f at 0x7f7459227758>
>>> f.__repr__ = lambda self: 'asdfgh'
>>> f 
<function f at 0x7f7459227758>
>>> f.__str__(f)
'qwerty'
>>> f.__repr__(f)
'asdfgh'
```

I know I can get the expected behavior by making a class with `__call__` (to make it look like a function) and `__str__` (to customize the string representation). Still, I'm curious if I can get something similar with regular functions.

Comment: Remember: dunder function are is looked up on the class not instances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. `__str__` and `__repr__` are special methods and thus are [always looked up on the type](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup-for-new-style-classes), not the instance. You'd have to override `type(f).__repr__` here, but that then would apply to *all* functions.

Your only realistic option then is to use a wrapper object with a `__call__` method:

```
def FunctionWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, callable):
        self._callable = callable
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._callable(*args, **kwargs)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<custom representation for {}>'.format(self._callable.__name__)
```

Answer (score 3):

As explained by MartijnPieters, you can't do it without going through a class.  But you can easily write a decorator which completely hides the added complexity:

```
from functools import update_wrapper

class _CustomReprFunc(object):
    def __init__(self, fn, repr_):
        self.fn = fn
        self.repr = repr_
        update_wrapper(self, fn)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.repr

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.fn(*args, **kwargs)


def custom_repr(repr_):
    def decorator(fn):
        return _CustomReprFunc(fn, repr_)
    return decorator
```

Usage:

```
@custom_repr('foobar')
def foo():
    """foo function"""
    return 'bar'
```